# Folium: TypeError Object of type 'DataFrame' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, pandas, folium

I'm using a simple .csv, which looks like this:

```
Latitude,Longitude,Count,Zero
49.978728,11.949353,100,0
49.978728,11.950353,2,0
```

Afterwards I turn it into a panda dataframe:

import pandas as pd
import folium
import numpy as np

```
 data = pd.read_csv("farmers_location.csv")

 #extract value from data
 count = data.loc[:, ["Count"]]
 latitude = data.loc[:, ["Latitude"]]
 longitude = data.loc[:, ["Longitude"]]

 #df_counters = pd.DataFrame(count,latitude,longitude)
 df_counters = count.join(latitude).join(longitude)
 df_counters.head()

 # forcely convert the numpy.int64 into string 
 df_counters['Count'] = df_counters['Count'].astype(str)


 locations = df_counters[['Latitude', 'Longitude']]
 locationlist = locations.values.tolist()
 len(locationlist)
 locationlist[1]
```

Afterwards I construct a map:

```
map = folium.Map(location=[49.978, 11.950], zoom_start=20)
for point in range(0, len(locationlist)):
     folium.Marker(locationlist[point], popup=df_counters['Count'] 
     [point]).add_to(map)
```

This works fine but, if I replace the last three lines with:

```
 map = folium.Map(location=[49.978, 11.950], zoom_start=12)
 for point in range(0, len(locationlist)):
      radius = count/20
      color1 = "#0A8A9F"
      color2= "#E37222"
      color= np.where(count>99, color1, color2)
      folium.CircleMarker(locationlist[point],
                          radius=radius,
                          color=color,
                          fill=True).add_to(map)
```

I end up with the following error:

> TypeError: Object of type 'DataFrame' is not JSON serializable

Edit: Since I solved the problem, here are two solutions:

You can turn color and radius into strings via str(color) and str(radius)